# Where is Statist plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, plugins

I am trying to install the Statist plugin to QGIS and I don't find it when I search within my plugins dialog. (see image) I'm running QGIS 2.18 on Ubuntu 18.04. I have the official QGIS plugin repository installed and no others. matplotlib and numpy are installed and updated to the latest versions. Can you help me find Statist?

[image]

I notice that it's not on the list of of plugins at the official repository site, is there another repository I should look for?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Statist plugin](https://plugins.bruy.me/statist.html) is not published in the official QGIS plugin repository. It's published on [Alexander Bruy's QGIS Plugins website](https://plugins.bruy.me/). Presumably you'll need to download it from [this site](https://plugins.bruy.me/plugins/plugins.xml#statist) and [install it manually](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins.html#the-install-from-zip-tab).

FYI, the minimum QGIS version for this plugin is QGIS 3.0.0. So you'll also need to [upgrade your QGIS version](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html).

Answer (score 2):

In addendum to CSK's answer:

No need to install it manually, just add the proper plugin XML to the QGIS plugin manager's repository list, like below:
https://plugins.bruy.me/plugins/plugins.xml

[image]
If you do so, you get auto-updates like any other QGIS plugin.

[image]